# Downcast from [PFObject]? to [PFObject] only unwraps optionals, did you mean to use "!"

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, pfobject

I am having an error appear in Xcode saying Downcast from '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use "!"?

```
    var iDArray = [String]()
var nameArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


        var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]
        for i in 0...objectIDs.count{
            self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectID") as! String)

            NSLog("\(objectIDs)")
```

[Xcode file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uO4L.png)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `guard` in this situation. Code below will safely unwrap optional `objectsArray` and, in case optional is `nil`, it will not execute further code. Also you can write this part of code a little more beautiful :)

```
ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() { (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        guard let objectIDs = objectsArray else { return }

        self.iDArray += objectIDs.map { $0.valueForKey("objectID") as! String }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did mean to use "!". Change this line:

```
var objectIDs = objectsArray as! [PFObject]
```

to this:

```
var objectIDs = objectsArray!
```

Since you are just unwrapping the array, there is no need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that a downcast is not needed because the compiler knows the type `[PFObject]?` – as you can see in the block signature.

The recommended way is first to handle the error. If it's nil you can safely unwrap the optional

```
ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
     // handle the error
    } else {
      for anObject in objectsArray! {
         self.iDArray.append(anObject["objectID"] as! String)
      }
    }
```